# Mysql - LIMIT by Percentage?

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

Say I define an alias 'count' in my Select Query and I want to limit the amount returned to count / 5 (or 20% of the table).

How can I do this?  Mysql doesn't seem to take anything but integers, not functions.

Answer (score 12):

Correct. The `LIMIT` clause takes an offset and a count of rows, not a percentage.  You're thinking of Microsoft SQL Server, which supports `SELECT TOP 20 PERCENT ...` (note that neither `LIMIT` or `TOP` are specified in standard SQL).

I would do this in two queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE ...conditions...

SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ...conditions... ORDER BY ...order... LIMIT ?
```

Replace the parameter `?` with the count / 5.

*You don't have to solve every problem in a single query.*

Comment: Just to add, I believe that running these two queries does *not* cause significant overhead, since MySQL should cache the result of the first query and the second one will actually run a lot faster.

Answer (score 5):

the LIMIT clause can takes 2 arguments and must be integers constants.

you can try something like this

```
SET @skip=1; SET @numrows=(select count(*) div 5 from tbl );
PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT ?, ?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @skip, @numrows;
```