# SQL Server 2012 Equivalent limit Pagination

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, pagination

What would be the syntax in SQL Server 2012 for the following MySQL Sql query:

```
select title,description,tags,post_date
  from myvids order by title desc 
   limit 0,20
```

Ref: [Use LIMIT to paginate results in MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728704/use-limit-to-paginate-results-in-mysql-query)

I want change the database to SQL Server.

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
             /********* For SQL Server 2012 & Later *********/

select [title]
      ,[description]
      ,tags
      ,post_date
from myvids 
ORDER BY [title] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY;
```