# How to implement pagination in custom query in backand

Tags: backand

I want to implement pagination in my custom query like it is done in the provided queries. I want to provide the number of rows and the page.

I tried the following but it seems that this is not possible:

```
SET @start = ('{{rows}}' * '{{page}}');
SELECT `table`.`text`, FROM `table`   
order by `table`.`text` desc
limit @start, {{rows}}
```

And this not either

```
...
limit {{rows * page}}, {{rows}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
        SET @records := {{rows}};
        PREPARE stmt FROM
        " SELECT    *
          FROM      Users
          LIMIT     ?, ?";

        SET @offset := @records * ({{page}} -1 );
        EXECUTE stmt USING @offset,@records;
```

Here is Back& docs on pagination
http://docs.backand.com/en/latest/what_would_you_like_to_do/retrieve_data/index.html#pagination

You are getting this error because
MySQL requires numeric constants for that LIMIT syntax.

see answer here 
[Use LIMIT to paginate results in MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728704/use-limit-to-paginate-results-in-mysql-query)