# How to make that function return none is field empty?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function `searchUser`, which return array user's data. The function works, however there is one problem. When the `search` parameter is empty then all the records from the database are there. And then the function should not return anything, right?

```js
    public function searchUser(string $search): array
    {
        $sql = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT user_id, first_name, last_name, avatar FROM user where first_name like :first_name or last_name like :last_name");
        $Search = "%$search%";
        $sql->bindParam(':first_name', $Search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sql->bindParam(':last_name', $Search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sql->execute();

        $search = [];
        if ($sql->rowCount()) {
            while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
                $search[] = new Search(
                    $row['user_id'],
                    $row['first_name'],
                    $row['last_name'],
                    $row['avatar']);
            }
        }
        return $search;
    }
```

Comment: And the question is ?  (Because the question "And then the function should not return anything, right?" is opinion based, and not suited for SO .... )

Comment: If the search button was pressed and the field is then empty, then no record should be returned then, and now it returns all

Comment: When you need to return nothing when searching for nothing, you can always add an if-statement like: `if ($search='') {.....} else { ` do whatever you need to do when you have a search item.

Comment: But if I add it then I mix the logic with persistence

Comment: As you use `"%$search%"`, with nothing in the field you end up with `"%%"` which will match all rows.

Comment: [Are questions of academic interest allowed on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330170/are-questions-of-academic-interest-allowed-on-stack-overflow)...  You might mix logic with persistence, but, who cares? 

Comment: BTW: Searching for a common-letter (like `e` or `a`) will (or might) also return a long list of names, so I do not see the problem that searching for an empty string will return all names.  When the long list is the problem you can have a look at: [Use LIMIT to paginate results in MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728704/use-limit-to-paginate-results-in-mysql-query)

Comment: I add my modified code, you look if that correct ?

Comment: To know if your code is correct, or to get a code review, you should post it here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The code works, but I want to know if I don't mix logic with perstistence

Answer (score -1):

```js
 public function searchUser(string $search): array|string
    {


        if ($search == '') {
            $noUser = 'No result';
            return $noUser;
        } else {

            $sql = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT user_id, first_name, last_name, avatar FROM user where first_name like :first_name or last_name like :last_name");
            $Search = "%$search%";
            $sql->bindParam(':first_name', $Search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sql->bindParam(':last_name', $Search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sql->execute();

            $search = [];
            if ($sql->rowCount()) {
                while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
                    $search[] = new Search(
                        $row['user_id'],
                        $row['first_name'],
                        $row['last_name'],
                        $row['avatar']);
                }
            }
        }
            return $search;
    }
```

Comment: if you don't want to mix logic with persistence then you must do this check elsewhere. before calling this function.