# MySQL: LIMIT by a percentage of the amount of records?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a list of values, like this:

```
id  value
----------
A   53
B   23
C   12
D   72
E   21
F   16
..
```

I need the top 10 ***percent*** of this list - I tried:

```
  SELECT id, value 
    FROM list
ORDER BY value DESC
   LIMIT COUNT(*) / 10
```

But this doesn't work. The problem is that I don't know the amount of records before I do the query.  Any idea's?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql set LIMIT to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309137/mysql-set-limit-to-string)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert SQL Server query to MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522433/convert-sql-server-query-to-mysql)

Comment: Best answer from the dups: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522433/convert-sql-server-query-to-mysql/5522462#5522462

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Best answer I found:

```
SELECT*
FROM    (
    SELECT list.*, @counter := @counter +1 AS counter
    FROM (select @counter:=0) AS initvar, list
    ORDER BY value DESC   
) AS X
where counter <= (10/100 * @counter);
ORDER BY value DESC
```

Change the 10 to get a different percentage.

Answer (score 5):

In case you are doing this for an out of order, or random situation - I've started using the following style:

```
SELECT id, value FROM list HAVING RAND() > 0.9
```

If you need it to be random but controllable you can use a seed (example with PHP):

```
SELECT id, value FROM list HAVING RAND($seed) > 0.9
```

Lastly - if this is a sort of thing that you need full control over you can actually add a column that holds a random value whenever a row is inserted, and then query using that

```
SELECT id, value FROM list HAVING `rand_column` BETWEEN 0.8 AND 0.9
```

Since this does not require sorting, or `ORDER BY` - it is O(n) rather than O(n lg n)

Comment: Note that these queries could return anything from no records to all of them (it's merely that the probability of any given record being in the resultset is 0.1).

Answer (score 3):

You can also try with that:

```
SET @amount =(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM page) /10;
PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT * FROM page LIMIT ?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @amount;
```

This is MySQL bug described in here: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=19795

Hope it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is VERY old, but it still pops up as the top result when you google SQL limit by percent so I'll try to save you some time. This is pretty simple to do these days. The following would give the OP the results they need:

```
    SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT
    id, 
    value 
    FROM list
    ORDER BY value DESC
```

To get a quick and dirty random 10 percent of your table, the following would suffice:

```
    SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT
    id, 
    value 
    FROM list
    ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Answer (score -1):

I have an alternative which hasn't been mentionned in the other answers: if you access from any language where you have full access to the MySQL API (i.e. not the MySQL CLI), you can launch the query, ask how many rows there will be and then break the loop if it is time.

E.g. in Python:

```
...
maxnum = cursor.execute(query)
for num, row in enumerate(query)
    if num > .1 * maxnum: # Here I break the loop if I got 10% of the rows.
        break
    do_stuff...
```

This works only with `mysql_store_result()`, not with `mysql_use_result()`, as the latter requires that you always accept all needed rows.

OTOH, the traffic for my solution might be too high - all rows have to be transferred.