# Limit by percentage of all rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How to limit by percentage of all rows in MySQL?

I was trying this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
ORDER BY column_name ASC
LIMIT (SELECT ROUND(COUNT(id)*0.25) FROM table_name)
```

I also tried to save query `SELECT ROUND(COUNT(id)*0.25) FROM table_name` to variable, but it was the same problem. I know that LIMIT require only number, but I don't know how many rows are in table to give specific number to LIMIT. How to do this without LIMIT if it isn't possible with LIMIT?

I need to SELECT only top 25 % of all rows in table.

Comment: Have a look at this:

[Stack Overflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741239/select-top-x-or-bottom-percent-for-numeric-values-in-mysql

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can use this code:

```
SELECT*
FROM    (
    SELECT list.*, @counter := @counter +1 AS counter
    FROM (select @counter:=0) AS initvar, list
    ORDER BY value DESC   
) AS X
where counter <= (10/100 * @counter);
ORDER BY value DESC
```

quote from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615172/mysql-limit-by-a-percentage-of-the-amount-of-records) duplicate question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615172/mysql-limit-by-a-percentage-of-the-amount-of-records

Comment: the query above is very inefficient considering a lot of better methods to accomplish this, like mentioned in the comment by Vignesh

Comment: This is a copy paste from the accepted answer to the duplicate question linked by Vignesh.

Comment: Thank you. It worked, but I needed to change this code a little.