# php calculating top ten percent from database?

Tags: php, mysql, percentile

I have this search running successfully that returns players skills and attributes. I want to get the top ten percent in particular columns. I was trying to use this:

```
$j=0;
while($percentile_row = mysql_fetch_array($percentile_result)){
    echo $percentile_row['user_id'].'<br />';
    $j++;
}
echo 'Total: '.$j.'<br />';
echo round(100/$j,1);

$players_worth = round(100/$j,1);

while($players_worth > 10){
    echo 'adding<br/>';
    $players_worth + $players_worth;
}
```

It seemed like a simple way to get it. It's just that the **$players_worth + $players_worth;** part isn't working when it's within the while loop. It works if I just echo it.

Or is there something I can add to the query that will make it select by a percentage? I have to do this for about 15 columns.

This is my existing query:

`SELECT user_id FROM Players ORDER BY user_id DESC`

Thank you for any tips you might have.

**Edit:**
I tried this, but no luck, when I var_dump it, it just says "bool(false)":
[MySQL: LIMIT by a percentage of the amount of records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615172/mysql-limit-by-a-percentage-of-the-amount-of-records)

Comment: _“It's just that the $players_worth + $players_worth; part isn't working”_ – it _is_ working, because it is a valid expression; but you are _doing_ nothing with the result of that expression. What do you want to accomplish by that? Do you want to double the value of `$players_worth`? Then do so, by using f.e. `$players_worth *= 2`.

Comment: I want to add itself to itself, but not double itself every time because the number would get out of hand. Currently, the number being produced is 1.4 so I want to add 1.4 on every pass, but as more entries are added to the table, that number will decrease so I can't make it static.

Comment: Well you can’t add the same value over and over again using just one variable …

Comment: Ah, so would $players_worth + $players_worth2; work by giving them the same value?

Comment: That is still an expression that just delivers a return value, but you are doing nothing with it. Looks like it’s time for you to go learn some basics, mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it and here's how I went about it:

First I got all the rows, then...

```
echo 'Total rows in table: '.$j.'<br />';

$twentyfive = floor($j*.25);
$fifteen = floor($j*.15);
$ten = floor($j*.1);


echo $ten.' '.$fifteen.' '.$twentyfive.'<br /><br />';


$topten=0;

while($topten < $ten && $percentile_row2 = mysql_fetch_array($percentile_result2)){

    $change =   "UPDATE Players SET " . $column['field'] ."=concat(" . $column['field'] . ",'%') WHERE user_id='" . $percentile_row2['user_id'] . "'";

    $wpdb->get_results($change);

    echo '<strong>in top 10%</strong> - '.$percentile_row2['field_1'].' - '.$percentile_row2['user_id'].'<br />';

$topten++;

}
```

And so on for the other percentiles. All the echoes were just to track it.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the number of records in the database, you could use LIMIT:

```
"SELECT user_id FROM Players ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT ".$rowCount*$percentage/100
```

I don't know of any way to use a percentage *directly* in a query, unless you already know the cutoff point for the value you're checking, which means you've already gone through the database and examined all the values.

Comment: I thought of that, but the number of rows will change over time. I guess I could do a query to get the total, put that in a variable, and use that for the math in the next query.

Comment: Yeah, you've got to know the number of rows one way or the other. It probably doesn't hurt if one or two rows are inserted or deleted in the middle of this, so long as the row count isn't too stale. See if you can get the count piggybacked on some other query you need to do anyway.