# Selecting Percentage that Varies

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking to write a query that selects a percentage of records using something like

select top 30 percent * from people

with a random order.

But I want to select more people if certain criteria is met. So I may want to select 35% where the nationality is Brazilian and a few other conditions.

What's the easiest way to do this? Thought I could use a union to a second query, but there may be several of these exceptions so is there a better way?

Comment: What do you mean by the "*top* 30 percent" ?

Comment: sqlfiddle.com your data and expected results please

Comment: MySQL syntax is `SELECT * FROM people LIMIT 5;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables to do it. Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @RecordsToReturn AS Decimal(16,2);
SET @RecordsToReturn AS (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable WHERE "Your Column" = 'Some Criteria') * .3
SELECT TOP (@RecordsToReturn) *
FROM YourTable
```

I dont have SQL server in front of me, but that should get you the first 30% of records based on the where criteria

Comment: The question has `mysql` tag!

Comment: My apologies, I posted MSSQL. Operator, you can probably use this Stackoverflow answer to get the top 30%. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615172/mysql-limit-by-a-percentage-of-the-amount-of-records The answer that is marked as answer should work, just change the ten to a 30