# Sample Rows with SQLDF

Tags: r, sample, sqldf

sqldf has a limit option to get 'X' rows. Can we also do a 'x%' sample using sqldf?

e.g.

```
> sqldf("select * from iris limit 3")

Loading required package: tcltk
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa

> sqldf("select * from iris sample 0.01")
Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  error in statement: near ".1": syntax error
```

Is there some workaround for this?

Manish

Comment: This is a completely valid question, but is there a reason you are using `sqldf` in `R`? Why not pure SQL? Or, if you like, why would another solution in R not be suitable here?

Comment: As the question is a sql question, possible duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615172/mysql-limit-by-a-percentage-of-the-amount-of-records)

Comment: @Hugh - I come from SQL background. So much more comfortable working in sqldf to alter tables/subselect cols and rows/group bys/havings etc. Hence want to do all that in SQL and then Sample rows.

Comment: See example 6e on the sqldf github page: https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is basically a SQL question. As `sqldf` uses SQLite by default (this is not absolutely correct, see the documentation for `drv` in `?sqldf` for more details), the question boils down to "How to select rows in random order in SQLite?". A simple answer can be found in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1253576/2706569):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

Using the example from the question:

```
> sqldf("select * from iris order by RANDOM() limit 3")
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1          6.3         3.3          4.7         1.6 versicolor
2          6.0         2.7          5.1         1.6 versicolor
3          5.0         2.0          3.5         1.0 versicolor
```

**EDIT:** If the *percentage* instead of the *number* of rows is given, the following could be used as a R solution. Pure SQLite solutions may exist.

```
percentage <- 0.02
mylimit <- round(nrow(iris) * percentage, 0)
sqldf(sprintf("select * from iris order by RANDOM() limit %d", mylimit))
```

Comment: This works fine. Just that when doing a group by or having clauses the nbr of rows can vary so we need 2 steps - one to create the calculated data frame and another to do the x% sampling once we have the rowcount.

Answer (score 1):

Not very elegant (SQL is not my strong point) but it works.

```
library(sqldf)
totalrows <- sqldf("SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfOrders FROM iris")
```

so....

```
10*totalrows[[1]]/100
```

get the "number" and put here:

```
sqldf("SELECT * FROM iris LIMIT number")
```

In any case, it is a question of sql rather than R

Answer (score 0):

Using 6e from the [sqldf home page](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf) we can get 10% of the records randomly from `iris` using SQL like this:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select * from iris order by random(*) limit 0.10 * (select count(*) from iris)")
```

To parameterize by the fraction try this:

```
frac <- 0.10
fn$sqldf("select * from iris order by random(*) limit $frac * (select count(*) from iris)")
```