# MySQL limit work around

Tags: mysql, limit

I need to limit records based on percentage but MYSQL does not allow that.  I need 10 percent `User Id` of `(count(`User Id`)/max(Total_Users_bynow)`
My code is as follows:

```
select * from flavia.TableforThe_top_10percent_of_the_user where `User Id` in (select distinct(`User Id`) from flavia.TableforThe_top_10percent_of_the_user group by `User Id` having count(distinct(`User Id`)) <= round((count(`User Id`)/max(Total_Users_bynow))*0.1)*count(`User Id`));
```

Kindly help.

Comment: No. Please see. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309137/mysql-limit-by-percentage

Comment: I knew this and thats why I am dividing count() by max(). but this calculation is not working. count() gives me  60028 and max() gives me 409272. but this calculation is not giving me right answer.

Comment: Something doesn't make sense. If you're grouping by User ID, then `COUNT(DISTINCT UserID)` will always be `1`.

Comment: Here is right query. I made little mistake in above one.

select *
from flavia.TableforThe_top_10percent_of_the_user
where `User Id` in 
(select distinct(`User Id`) from flavia.TableforThe_top_10percent_of_the_user group by `User Id` having count(distinct(`User Id`)) <= round((count(`User Id`)/max(Total_Users_bynow))*0.1)*count(`User Id`))

Comment: @ Barmer: ... Please let me know if you have solution.

Comment: @GauravGupta Don't try to put code in comments, edit the question. Please format it nicely, like I did. Use the `{ }` tool in the SO editor to mark literal code.

Comment: I am trying to pull 10 percent users

Comment: @Barmar  I edited code at the top (in question itself)..kindly help

Comment: Why didn't you use the Code tool in the SO editor? Mark your code, and click on `{}` in the toolbar. Not put `{` and `}` in the question.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do. Please update the question and state clearly what you mean by "limit records based on percentage". It looks like you want 10% of something, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Post some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Edited just now. Trying to figure out about how to post sample data to you.

Comment: @GauravGupta If you want to post a data sample, maybe you can go to [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) and create a working example of what you're trying to do

Comment: @ Barmar ... Thanks for checking my problem and trying to help me. I got solution----------  set @numerator := (select count(distinct(`User Id`)) from flavia.TableforThe_top_10percent_of_the_user);
set @denomenator := (select max(Total_Users_bynow) from flavia.TableforThe_top_10percent_of_the_user);
set @totaluser := (round(((@numerator/@denomenator)*0.1)*@numerator));
set @counts:= 0;

select *,@counts:=if(@currentuserid like `User Id`, @counts,@counts+1),@currentuserid:=`User Id`from flavia.TableforThe_top_10percent_of_the_user where @counts<=@totaluser;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider splitting your problem in pieces. You can use user variables to get what you need. [Quoting from this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309137/mysql-limit-by-percentage):

> *You don't have to solve every problem in a single query.*

<strike>So... let's get this done. I'll not put your full query, but some examples:</strike>

```
-- Step 1. Get the total of the rows of your dataset
set @nrows = (select count(*) from (select ...) as a);
-- --------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^
-- The full original query (or, if possible a simple version of it) goes here

-- Step 2. Calculate how many rows you want to retreive
-- You may use "round()", "ceiling()" or "floor()", whichever fits your needs
set @limrows = round(@nrows * 0.1);

-- Step 3. Run your query:
select ...
limit @limrows;
```

---

After checking, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245180/variable-limit-clause-in-mysql) which says that my above approach won't work. There's, however, an alternative:

```
-- Step 1. Get the total of the rows of your dataset
set @nrows = (select count(*) from (select ...) as a);
-- --------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^
-- The full original query (or, if possible a simple version of it) goes here

-- Step 2. Calculate how many rows you want to retreive
-- You may use "round()", "ceiling()" or "floor()", whichever fits your needs
set @limrows = round(@nrows * 0.1);

-- Step 3. (UPDATED) Run your query. 
--         You'll need to add a "rownumber" column to make this work.
select *
from (select @rownum := @rownum+1 as rownumber
           , ... -- The rest of your columns
      from (select @rownum := 0) as init
         , ... -- The rest of your FROM definition
      order by ... -- Be sure to order your data
     ) as a
where rownumber <= @limrows
```

Hope this helps (I think it will work without a quirk this time)

Comment: Are you sure limit @limrows works, cause its showing me error here.