# MySql Using multiple queries simultaneously

Tags: mysql

I am fairly new to sql and am trying to understand the working of Limit. I wrote this code in MySql using the following code inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/1309211/11570812.

```
select count(*) from station as c;
select * from station
order by ID
limit c;
```

But it throws the following error

ERROR 1327 (42000) at line 2: Undeclared variable: c

Can anyone suggest how to use the value from one query into another query and the reason for this error.

Comment: Those are two **separate** queries.

Comment: What are you trying to do? The limit won't really help since you want to get all the rows anyway... is it?

Comment: I know this code won't do anything different but to learn how to use values found from one query into another is my primary objective.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend `percent_rank()`:

```
select *
from (
    select s.*, percent_rank() over(order by id) pr
    from station s
) s
where pr <= 0.2
```

Comment: Here's a doc link to the [percent_rank() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_percent-rank). Note this requires MySQL 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

To produce the result you want you'll need to combine those two queries into a single one. You do that by using *subqueries*.

For example, if you wanted the first half of the table (ordered by `ID`) you could use two subqueries:

```
select
from ( -- this is a "table expression" subquery
  select *,
    row_number() over(order by id) as rn
  from station
) x
where rn <= ( -- this is a typical "old school" subquery
  select count(*) / 2 from station
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

```
select count(*) from station as c;

select * from station
order by ID
limit c;
```

Problem 1: These are two separate queries. Column aliases only last until the end of the query they are defined in. Therefore you can't reference `c` in the second query.

Problem 2: `LIMIT` requires either an integer literal or a query parameter. You can't use aliases or variables as the arguments for `LIMIT`.

So you can't do what you show, without using dynamic SQL. I showed this in [the answer you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1309211/20860).